# Is there a way to Group by one column and then group by second column starting string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of Cars available in our township. I want to display the overall result of cars in a table where first I show number of cars of a particular make then when that result is clicked, I should show number of cars in a particular model of a particular make.

[Pl see the table structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G6yc.png%3Cbr%3E)

Table structure:

| Make | Model | Year | Fuel | Engine_cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maruti | Brezza ZDI | 2019 | Diesel | 1199 |
| Maruti | Brezza VXi | 2020 | Petrol | 1499 |
| Maruti | Brezza Lxi | 2021 | Petrol | 1499 |
| Maruti | Baleno MT | 2019 | PEtrol | 1199 |
| Hyundai | Creta | 2020 | Petrol | 1199 |
| Hyundai | Aura | 2021 | Petrol | 1199 |

Code used

```
$mysql = "SELECT make, model FROM cars car_make WHERE make = (SELECT model FROM cars WHERE make like = cars_make.make) GROUP BY make, model";
$myresult = mysqli_query($connect, $mysql);
echo var_dump($myresult);
```

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text, just put that text in your post](/help/how-to-ask) (with proper [markdown](/markdown) of course). And also show what code you already wrote to try to solve this problem yourself. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, it's a "helping you figure out a problem with your code" Q&A site.

Comment: What did you attempt ? (show your code)

Comment: $mysql = "SELECT make, model FROM cars car_make WHERE make = (SELECT model FROM cars WHERE make like = cars_make.make) GROUP BY make, model";
 $myresult = mysqli_query($connect, $mysql);
 echo var_dump($myresult);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to use two queries

```sql
select make, count(make) from cars group by make
```

This will give you makes and their counts

```sql
select make, model, count(model) from cars group by make, model
```

This will give the break down for each make.

You can combine the two queries into one, but then you have to do some php processing.  Like this

```sql
select make, model, count(make), count(model) from cars, group by make, model
```